# For nested comments, how can I pass the parent-comment's ID to the comments form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have successfully created comments with the following form, when the comment refers directly to an article.

```
<%= form_with(model: [@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
 
 <p>Comment:</p>
 <%= f.text_area :body, class:'' %>
 <%= image_submit_tag("Post.jpg", height: "25", width: "25", class: "mt-5 ms-3") %>
<% end %>
```

But, now I am attempting to create nested comments, and I am stuck without knowing how to pass the parent-comment's ID to the form, when the form is accessed as a reply to a previously created comment, or how to pass a nil parent-comment ID, when the form is accessed directly from the article itself and referring to that article.

In app/views/articles/show.html.erb, where the comment form is called up so as to create a comment directly on the article, this is what I have tried out:

```
<%= render '/comments/comment_form', locals: {article: @article, parent: nil} %>
```

In app/views/comments/show.html.erb, where the form is called up as a reply to a previously created comment, this is what I have tried out:

```
 <%= render '/comments/comment_form', locals: {article: comment.article, parent: comment} %>
```

Before trying to create the nested comments, I merely rendered the form from articles/show.html.erb without passing anything (no locals: {etc.}) and it worked beautifully.

I would very much appreciate some guidance in this matter. Following is all the rest of code that I believe pertinent to the matter.

In app/models/comments.rb

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :commenter, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Comment', optional: true

  has_many :comments, foreign_key: :parent_id

  validates_presence_of :body, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 500 }
end
```

In app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params.merge(commenter: current_user))
    @comment.article_id = params[:article_id]
    @comment.save
    redirect_to article_path(params[:article_id])
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :article_id, :user_id, :parent_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you are looking at this the wrong way up, you need an articles form, you need accepts nested attributes on the has_many comments, you need to add the comments form as a `fields_for comments` in the articles form and add the nested attributes to the accepted params in the artticles controller and forget completely about the comments controller. The comments should be built in the articles controller and not in your form. Have a google for accepts nested attributes, this might help https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

Comment: @jamesc thats not a good idea. The articles and comments are created by different users in completely different contexts. There is no good reason why ArticlesController should be dealing with both. Nested attributes is not the answer to every problem.

Comment: @jamesc in fact nested attributes should only be used to solve the problem when you want to create or modify the parent record and it's children *at the same time*. I don't need to change this question to comment on it.

Comment: @max, thank for your insight, I would not suggest anything else, I just misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing instance variables and [locals](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) which is really easy to do.

Anything with the `@` sigil is an instance variable in Ruby. The way it works in Rails is that all the instance variables in your controller are made available to the views via the *view context* which is the context passed to the template engine. Think of it basically as *self* inside your views.

Local assigns on the other hand are passed when you call render and are called as normal methods or through the `local_assigns` method. Rails then delegates these calls to the view context through metaprogramming. These calls should not have the `@` sigil. It's also worth noting that view *locals* should not be confused for *local variables* which is a language feature.

So lets start by changing the partial to actually use locals:

```
<%= form_with(model: [local_assigns(:parent), comment]) do |f| %>
  # ..
<% end %>
```

`local_assigns(:parent)` is a nifty little trick to avoid a NoMethodError if the local is not passed and can be used to make the same form reusable for shallow nesting.

You should also never do `@article.comments.build` in a form. Instanciating the model is the job of the controller and not the view. The form will also always be bound to a new instance which means that any user input will be lost if the form is invalid and you're breaking the form for editing!

On the controller side there are two different ways to handle resources that can be nested in multiple different resources. The first way is by routing everything into a single controller and using the "param sniffing approach":

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_parent
  
  # Creates articles nested in a Article or in another Comment
  # POST /articles/1/comments
  # POST /comments/2/comments
  def create
    @comment = @parent.comments.new(comment_params) do |c|
      c.user = current_user
    end
    # don't assume that saving will always be successful
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @parent
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_parent
    if params[:article_id].present?
      @parent = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    elsif params[:comment_id].present?
      @parent = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
    end
  end

  def comment_params
    # you should not be permitting any of those params!
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

While this is popular I'm not a huge fan of this approach as it gets really ugly as the complexity grows. It also completely ignores the Single Responibilty Principle. For example you might want to redirect differently depending on the parent type.

The second aprroach is to use composition and create separate controllers:

```
resouces :articles do 
  resouces :comments, only: :create, module: :articles
end

resouces :comments, only: [] do 
  resouces :comments, only: :create, module: :comments
end
```

```
# Creates Comments on an Article 
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_parent
  
  # Creates comments nested in a parent record. 
  # This parent record should be set by subclasses. 
  def create
    @comment = @parent.comments.new(comment_params) do |c|
      c.user = current_user
    end
    # don't assume that saving will always be successful
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @parent
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_parent
    raise "This method must be implemented by subclasses!"
  end

  def comment_params
    # you should not be permitting any of those params!
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

```
module Articles 
  # Creates Comments on an Article 
  class CommentsController < ::CommentsController 
    private

    def set_parent
      @parent = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    end
  end
end
```

```
module Comments 
  # Creates Comments nested in another Comment 
  class CommentsController < ::CommentsController 
    private

    def set_parent
      @parent = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: A little word of advice if I may. What you're doing is venturing into pretty advanced territory in Rails and you should make sure you have got all the basics nailed down before you attempt it or you're going to struggle a lot. Understanding when (and how) to nest resources and how to deal with resources that "live" on another resources views is harder then you would think.